# C Program pass by value

Tags: c

I have a completed C program that prompts the user to input a number between 0 and 100000. Then prints out each digit of the number. My code completes the task, but it does not properly pass by value through functions which would be ideal. I need some advice on how to take what I have and make it properly pass the user value by function and return.

```
    #include <stdio.h>


    void print_1(int,int);
    void print_10(int,int);
    void print_100(int,int);
    void print_1000(int,int);
    void print_10000(int,int);

    int main() {
        int userInput;
        printf("Please enter a positive number less than 100,000: \n");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
        if (userInput > 0 && userInput < 100000)
        {
            printf("\nYou have entered: %d\n",userInput);;

        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nThe number you have entered is out of the specified range\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        int lastDigit;
        print_1(userInput,lastDigit);


    } //End main


// ===========================================================================
//  Function      : Print_1
//  Description   : Prints out the 1st digit of user input
//
//  Input         :
//                  input userInput
//                  output userInput
//  Return value  :
//                 return value
//
//  Notes: This function repeats several printing the lastDigit then slicing it
//  off before passing on to a new function.
//============================================================================
     void print_1(int userInput,int lastDigit)
            {
            lastDigit = userInput % 10;
            printf("\n1\'s:     %d \n", lastDigit);
            userInput = (userInput - lastDigit) / 10;\
            print_10(userInput,lastDigit);
            } // end print_1

// ===========================================================================
//  Function      : Print_10
//  Description   : Prints out the 1st digit of user input
//
//  Input         :
//                  input userInput
//                  output userInput
//  Return value  :
//                 return value
//
//  Notes: This function repeats several printing the lastDigit then slicing it
//  off before passing on to a new function.
//============================================================================
    void print_10(int userInput,int lastDigit)
            {
            lastDigit = userInput % 10;
            printf("\n10\'s:    %d \n", lastDigit);
            userInput = (userInput - lastDigit) / 10;
            print_100(userInput,lastDigit);
            } // end print_10

// ===========================================================================
//  Function      : Print_100
//  Description   : Prints out the 1st digit of user input
//
//  Input         :
//                  input userInput
//                  output userInput
//  Return value  :
//                 return value
//
//  Notes: This function repeats several printing the lastDigit then slicing it
//  off before passing on to a new function.
//============================================================================
    void print_100(int userInput,int lastDigit)
            {
            lastDigit = userInput % 10;
            printf("\n100\'s:   %d \n", lastDigit);
            userInput = (userInput - lastDigit) / 10;
            print_1000(userInput,lastDigit);
            } //end print_100

// ===========================================================================
//  Function      : Print_1000
//  Description   : Prints out the 1st digit of user input
//
//  Input         :
//                  input userInput
//                  output userInput
//  Return value  :
//                 return value
//
//  Notes: This function repeats several printing the lastDigit then slicing it
//  off before passing on to a new function.
//============================================================================
    void print_1000(int userInput,int lastDigit)
            {
            lastDigit = userInput % 10;
            printf("\n1000\'s:  %d \n", lastDigit);
            userInput = (userInput - lastDigit) / 10;
            print_10000(userInput,lastDigit);
            } //end print_1000

// ===========================================================================
//  Function      : Print_10000
//  Description   : Prints out the 1st digit of user input
//
//  Input         :
//                  input userInput
//                  output userInput
//  Return value  :
//                 return value
//
//  Notes: This function repeats several printing the lastDigit then slicing it
//  off before passing on to a new function.
//============================================================================
    void print_10000(int userInput,int lastDigit)
            {
            lastDigit = userInput % 10;
            printf("\n10000\'s: %d \n", lastDigit);
            userInput = (userInput - lastDigit) / 10;
            return userInput;
            }//end print_10000

             //End Program
```

Comment: What does this code do? And why is this so messed up?

Comment: All of the function arguments in your code are passed by value.

Comment: _but it does not properly pass by value through functions which would be ideal_ - that statement does not seem to reflect anything valid in the code you've pasted. Perhaps you should describe the problem you're having rather than what you think is the cause.

Comment: These print functions could be a single print function. Also: "return value: return value" ... this is not what is meant by documenting your code!

Comment: In the last function you have a void return type yet your returning int.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve this that code, but every one of your args is passed by value.  In your code:

```
int lastDigit;
print_1(userInput,lastDigit);
```

You're passing an uninitialized variable, lastDigit.  You are basically sending "gibberish" to your print_ functions.  While it has no affect on the outcome because you are initializing it inside the functions, that is bad practice that will likely get you into trouble later.  You should change them all: remove the lastDigit argument and declare it locally, like so:

```
void print_1(int userInput)
{
   int lastDigit = userInput % 10;
```

If, however, you want lastDigit to retain the value set inside of your function, you need to pass by address.

```
int lastDigit;
print_1(userInput, &lastDigit);
```

And modify your prototypes like so:

```
void print_1(int userInput, int *lastDigit)
```

AND YOU WILL HAVE TO MODIFY EVERY USAGE OF THAT VARIABLE INSIDE YOUR CODE.  Those caps were meant as a warning, just in case were so inclined to make that argument change.  You'll need to read up on pointers first.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

Answer (score 0):

In your program you need to initialize the `lastDigit`, compiler will compain about it.

```
int lastDigit = 0;
```

Also you need not to pass the `lastDigit` in your method, since it is not doing anything in your program.

Instead of this, you can use remainder to find out the last digits. Here's the same code.

```
int main() {
        int userInput;
        printf("Please enter a positive number less than 100,000: \n");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
        if (userInput > 0 && userInput < 100000)
        {
            printf("\nYou have entered: %d\n",userInput);;

        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nThe number you have entered is out of the specified range\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        int inputValue = userInput;
        int count = 1;

        while(inputValue > 0)
        {
            int remainder = inputValue % 10;
            inputValue = inputValue / 10;
            printf("\nThe %d value is %d \n", count, remainder);
            count++;
        }
 return 0;

}
```